# Why can't I `map` over a Swift dictionary lookup value optional?

Tags: swift

According to the [Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH4-SW6), a Swift dictionary lookup using the subscript operator returns a possible value wrapped in an `Optional`. I can verify this by pattern matching against it:

```
let d = [ "a": 1, "b": 2]

switch d["a"] {
    case .Some(let x): print(x)
    case .None: print("Nothing")
}
```

But, when I try to use the `Optional` type's `map` method on the lookup value:

```
d["a"].map { print($0 * 2) }
```

I get an error:

```
24:1: error: '(String, Int)' does not have a member named 'map'
d["a"].map { print($1 * 2) }
^ ~~~
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I tried that in playground and had no issue running it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
d["a"].map { print($1 * 2) }
                    ^~~~ you mean $0
```

Faced with this, Swift is giving you its best guess based on the other kind of subscript (which takes Dictionary index and gives you a key/value pair, so would provide a second argument).

Comment: We all do things like this from time to time :-)